# How to perform $redact stage in .net Mongo Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using C# MongoDB.Driver version 2.4.3.  I have successfully projected the data into a new BSonDocument and want to use $redact but it does not look like the driver supports that stage. Is there a different way to create the stage in C#?

```
var collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myCollection");
var test = collection.Aggregate().Project("{\"_id\":1, \"name\":\"$name.fullName\"");
```

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370829/get-all-objects-where-a-property-matches-a-value-nested-in-array/43371475#43371475

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer.